# кастомный инспектор unity

Tags: unity3d

попытался сделать кастомный инспектор для некоторых компонентов, и столкнулся с проблемой.

```
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class transform : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Transform unit = target as Transform;

        Undo.RecordObject(target, "позиция");
        unit.localPosition = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("позиция", unit.localPosition);


        Undo.RecordObject(target, "размер");
        unit.localScale = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("размер", unit.localScale);


        Undo.RecordObject(target, "поаорот");
        float rotation = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("поаорот", unit.localEulerAngles.y);
}
```

как сделать вот такой параметр поворота вместо Vector2Field,
чтобы можно было изменить только вращение по оси Y?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

все решил.

```
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Transform unit = target as Transform;

        Undo.RecordObject(target, "позиция");
        unit.localPosition = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("позиция", unit.localPosition);

        Undo.RecordObject(target, "размер");
        unit.localScale = EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field("размер", unit.localScale);

        Undo.RecordObject(target, "паворот");
        float rotationZ = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("поаорот", unit.localEulerAngles.z);
        unit.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(unit.localEulerAngles.x, unit.localEulerAngles.y, rotationZ);
    }
```